# 100 books in 10 identical bags

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Show that the number of ways of distributing 100 identical books into
>   10 indistinguishable bags so that no two bags contain the same of number of
>   books and no bag is empty, is the same as the number of ways of
>   distributing 55 identical objects into 10 bags so that no bag is
>   empty.

I think I have solved the second part of the question correctly as:

$x_1+ x_2+.....+x_{10}= 45$  (Technique: Stars and Bars)

This has$\dbinom {55}{45}$  solutions.

Now how do I solve the first part?

Progress till now:

We need solutions of

$x_1+x_2....+x_{10} = 90$

This has $\dbinom{99}{90}$ solutions. Now from this how do I eliminate the solutions when any two bags contain same number of books? It seems to be really tough. 
Also, the bags are identical which adds to the trouble.

Comment: Careful - the bags are identical, so stars and bars will overcount your part 2 answer. You are dealing with partitions here.

Comment: @Joffan in part 2 of the question, the bags aren't identical

Comment: For the two cases to be the same, the bags must be indistinguishable in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The number of partitions of $100$ into $10$ unequal parts is given by the coefficient of $y^{10} x^{100}$ in

$$ \prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+y x^{n}\right) $$
which by Joffan's remark is given by the number of partitions of $100-45=55$ into $10$ parts, i.e. by the coefficient of $y^{10}x^{55}$ in
$$ \prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+yx^{n}+y^2x^{2n}+\ldots\right) = \prod_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{1-yx^n}=\frac{1-y}{(y;x)_{\infty}}$$
in terms of [q-Pochhammer symbols](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html). This also is the coefficient of $x^{55}$ in $\frac{x^{10}}{t(x)}$, where $t(x)$ is a polynomial with degree $55$ and coefficients in $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$, which can be factored as

$$t(x)=(x-1)^{10}(x+1)^5 \Phi_3(x)^2\Phi_4(x)^2 \Phi_5(x)^2\Phi_6(x)\Phi_7(x)\Phi_8(x)\Phi_9(x)\Phi_{10}(x).$$
By partial fraction decomposition and lengthy computations we have that the final outcome should be $\color{red}{33401}$.

Comment: I was fully aware that the calculation of the actual result was beyond my limited powers, so stuck to showing that the two cases are equivalent.

Comment: Answer given is 55C44

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the number of distinct [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $100$ items into $10$ non-equal parts.

As partitions are unordered (because the bags are indistinguishable), we can choose to have them in ascending order. Then since we are aware that each bag's book count is strict bigger than the previous bag, we can subtract off $0,1,2,\ldots$ books from the successive bags to leave a partition which is still ordered, still nonzero books in each bag, but now the adjacent bags may have identical book counts. Here we have removed a total of $45$ books for a $10$-way partition over $55$ remaining books without the requirement for all-different book counts.

---

Using the recursive definition of $p_k(n)$, the number of distinct partitions of $n$ items into exactly $k$ non-zero parts, that

$p_k(n) = p_k(n-k) + p_{k-1}(n-1)$

with $p_k(n) = 0$ when $n<k$ and $p_1(n) =1$, we can get the exact value of $p_{10}(55)$ in a spreadsheet calculation, which happily agrees with Jack D'Aurizio's result:

$$\small\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
n \downarrow \quad k \to 
& \;\;1\;\; & \;\;2\;\; & \;\;3\;\; & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
4 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
5 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
6 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
7 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
8 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
9 & 1 & 4 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
10 & 1 & 5 & 8 & 9 & 7 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
11 & 1 & 5 & 10 & 11 & 10 & 7 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
12 & 1 & 6 & 12 & 15 & 13 & 11 & 7 & 5 & 3 & 2 \\ \hline
13 & 1 & 6 & 14 & 18 & 18 & 14 & 11 & 7 & 5 & 3 \\ \hline
14 & 1 & 7 & 16 & 23 & 23 & 20 & 15 & 11 & 7 & 5 \\ \hline
15 & 1 & 7 & 19 & 27 & 30 & 26 & 21 & 15 & 11 & 7 \\ \hline
16 & 1 & 8 & 21 & 34 & 37 & 35 & 28 & 22 & 15 & 11 \\ \hline
17 & 1 & 8 & 24 & 39 & 47 & 44 & 38 & 29 & 22 & 15 \\ \hline
18 & 1 & 9 & 27 & 47 & 57 & 58 & 49 & 40 & 30 & 22 \\ \hline
19 & 1 & 9 & 30 & 54 & 70 & 71 & 65 & 52 & 41 & 30 \\ \hline
20 & 1 & 10 & 33 & 64 & 84 & 90 & 82 & 70 & 54 & 42 \\ \hline
21 & 1 & 10 & 37 & 72 & 101 & 110 & 105 & 89 & 73 & 55 \\ \hline
22 & 1 & 11 & 40 & 84 & 119 & 136 & 131 & 116 & 94 & 75 \\ \hline
23 & 1 & 11 & 44 & 94 & 141 & 163 & 164 & 146 & 123 & 97 \\ \hline
24 & 1 & 12 & 48 & 108 & 164 & 199 & 201 & 186 & 157 & 128 \\ \hline
25 & 1 & 12 & 52 & 120 & 192 & 235 & 248 & 230 & 201 & 164 \\ \hline
26 & 1 & 13 & 56 & 136 & 221 & 282 & 300 & 288 & 252 & 212 \\ \hline
27 & 1 & 13 & 61 & 150 & 255 & 331 & 364 & 352 & 318 & 267 \\ \hline
28 & 1 & 14 & 65 & 169 & 291 & 391 & 436 & 434 & 393 & 340 \\ \hline
29 & 1 & 14 & 70 & 185 & 333 & 454 & 522 & 525 & 488 & 423 \\ \hline
30 & 1 & 15 & 75 & 206 & 377 & 532 & 618 & 638 & 598 & 530 \\ \hline
31 & 1 & 15 & 80 & 225 & 427 & 612 & 733 & 764 & 732 & 653 \\ \hline
32 & 1 & 16 & 85 & 249 & 480 & 709 & 860 & 919 & 887 & 807 \\ \hline
33 & 1 & 16 & 91 & 270 & 540 & 811 & 1009 & 1090 & 1076 & 984 \\ \hline
34 & 1 & 17 & 96 & 297 & 603 & 931 & 1175 & 1297 & 1291 & 1204 \\ \hline
35 & 1 & 17 & 102 & 321 & 674 & 1057 & 1367 & 1527 & 1549 & 1455 \\ \hline
36 & 1 & 18 & 108 & 351 & 748 & 1206 & 1579 & 1801 & 1845 & 1761 \\ \hline
37 & 1 & 18 & 114 & 378 & 831 & 1360 & 1824 & 2104 & 2194 & 2112 \\ \hline
38 & 1 & 19 & 120 & 411 & 918 & 1540 & 2093 & 2462 & 2592 & 2534 \\ \hline
39 & 1 & 19 & 127 & 441 & 1014 & 1729 & 2400 & 2857 & 3060 & 3015 \\ \hline
40 & 1 & 20 & 133 & 478 & 1115 & 1945 & 2738 & 3319 & 3589 & 3590 \\ \hline
41 & 1 & 20 & 140 & 511 & 1226 & 2172 & 3120 & 3828 & 4206 & 4242 \\ \hline
42 & 1 & 21 & 147 & 551 & 1342 & 2432 & 3539 & 4417 & 4904 & 5013 \\ \hline
43 & 1 & 21 & 154 & 588 & 1469 & 2702 & 4011 & 5066 & 5708 & 5888 \\ \hline
44 & 1 & 22 & 161 & 632 & 1602 & 3009 & 4526 & 5812 & 6615 & 6912 \\ \hline
45 & 1 & 22 & 169 & 672 & 1747 & 3331 & 5102 & 6630 & 7657 & 8070 \\ \hline
46 & 1 & 23 & 176 & 720 & 1898 & 3692 & 5731 & 7564 & 8824 & 9418 \\ \hline
47 & 1 & 23 & 184 & 764 & 2062 & 4070 & 6430 & 8588 & 10156 & 10936 \\ \hline
48 & 1 & 24 & 192 & 816 & 2233 & 4494 & 7190 & 9749 & 11648 & 12690 \\ \hline
49 & 1 & 24 & 200 & 864 & 2418 & 4935 & 8033 & 11018 & 13338 & 14663 \\ \hline
50 & 1 & 25 & 208 & 920 & 2611 & 5427 & 8946 & 12450 & 15224 & 16928 \\ \hline
51 & 1 & 25 & 217 & 972 & 2818 & 5942 & 9953 & 14012 & 17354 & 19466 \\ \hline
52 & 1 & 26 & 225 & 1033 & 3034 & 6510 & 11044 & 15765 & 19720 & 22367 \\ \hline
53 & 1 & 26 & 234 & 1089 & 3266 & 7104 & 12241 & 17674 & 22380 & 25608 \\ \hline
54 & 1 & 27 & 243 & 1154 & 3507 & 7760 & 13534 & 19805 & 25331 & 29292 \\ \hline
55 & 1 & 27 & 252 & 1215 & 3765 & 8442 & 14950 & 22122 & 28629 & 
\color{red}{33401} \\ \hline
\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Sorry, unable to understand completely.

Comment: Also, do you mean we should preload bags with 1 book, 2 books, etc? then what if the bag preloaded with 3 has solution 0 and the one preloaded with 2 books has solution 1... Again, both bags will contain 3 books (same number)

Comment: @Abcd Just to add some details to this answer: Given any distribution of $55$ books into $10$ bags, order it in ascending order, add $0$ book to the  first bag, $1$ book to the second...$9$ books to the tenth, then you have a distribution of $100$ books into $10$ bags with every bag having different numbers of books. Conversely, given a distribution with the first method, ordering the bags and subtracting $0,1,\ldots,9$ bags give a distribution with the second method.

Comment: @Abcd To go in the reverse direction, distribute the $55$ books to bags, order them in increasing size (which may include equal book counts), then add $0,1,2,3,\ldots,9$ books to the successive bags to get back to the $100$ book case with unequal bags. You don't preload because you can't add books until the partition of books is sorted into size order.

Comment: OK, then part 1 will also yield $\dbinom {55}{45}$... in the comments you have said that bags should be identical in both cases.. if that's the case why do my answers match for both cases even when I took distinguishable bags for second case.

Comment: Answer given is 55C44

Comment: That does not match the problem as described here.